# Prove that $r+x$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

The question is:
Let $r$ be rational and $x$ be irrational. Prove that $r+x$ is irrational.

I realize that this question has been asked before, but I have a doubt about an approach different from assuming $r = \frac{p}{q}$.

Assume $r+x$ is rational. Since $r \in \mathbb{Q}, \,\,\exists (-r) \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r + (-r) = 0$.

By the closure property of the field of rational numbers, if $ (-r), (r+x) \in \mathbb{Q}$, then

$$ x = 0 + x = (-r + r) + x = (-r) + (r+x) \in \mathbb{Q}$$

which is a contradiction, therefore $r+x$ must be irrational.

However, I have a doubt about the first equality. Since $x$ is irrational, would we be able to conclude that $0+x=x$ as this axiom of additive identity only holds for the rational numbers, and we haven't been introduced to the field of real numbers yet.

Comment: What is the question? What is $r$? What is $x$?

Comment: What does "irrational" mean to you if you "haven't been introduced to the field of real numbers yet"?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Sorry, $r$ is a rational number, and $x$ is irrational.

Comment: How does the proof here differ from the one at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886155/question-about-proof-that-r-x-in-mathbbi Snow?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh I did not know that the proof was already there. However, my doubt was about a specific step in the proof, as stated in the question. If this is against the rules of the site, I could delete my question, if that's what's required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides *Anne Bauval*'s pertinent remark in the comments, in the first place you need to have already assumed or constructed **addition on ℝ**, otherwise you are simply ***forbidden*** from writing "$r+x$" in the first place given reals $r,x$. And certainly you would have the basic arithmetic fact $0+x = x$, either assumed or proven, otherwise that addition would be meaningless and you would not be using it.

Comment: yes you are right. I was just confused about the identity axiom, but the definition of $r+x$ itself gives gives the real numbers. thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Snow: I think you need to understand more clearly that the real numbers is an entire **structure** ⟨ℝ,0,1,+,·,<⟩ that satisfies certain properties, and not just a set ℝ. You can't meaningfully call anything a "real number" unless it belongs to such a structure. For problems of the kind you wanted to solve, we would assume the usual properties. If you're not sure which properties you are allowed to assume, then your teacher needs to be more precise. ∀x∈ℝ ( 0+x = x ) *is* one of those properties!

Comment: i understand! i was trying to prove the above statement using as less axioms as i could (only the field properties of $\mathbb{Q}$). But in doing so, I cannot work with these operations for an irrational number $x$. Therefore, I must assume the axioms for the addition operation of real numbers to even work with numbers such as $r+x$. Got it!

Comment: @Snow: That's right!